# How to prepend a 2-byte string size and send it over TCP

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, endianness

I have an application which sends received UDP packets over TCP connection.
I'm storing the UDP packet data in a `std::string` object.

For TCP send/receive, I'm using a data encoding/decoding scheme as `<2-byte data length><Data>`.

This is my requirement.

How do I prepend the **2-bytes string length** to the `std::string` efficiently?

Also, do I need to take care of endianess also (hostToNetwork) for the 2-byte length integer? Also, for the data part?

Comment: Store the data at a two-byte offset, fill in the length once you know what it is.

Comment: cannot. The udp data is passed to one parser engine and it return the string object which i need to prepand it with its length and send it.

Comment: You can't prepend efficiently (i.e. without moving the other data). On the other hand, it's just moving a UDP packet's worth of data, which is pretty fast. Is this operation really a bottleneck? (BTW, it's not obvious why you're not just adding this in the parser.)

Comment: You probably want to take care of endianness of the size. If you're just receiving and resending UDP packets, you shouldn't modify the packet data in any way.

Comment: ..or just call send( ) twice, once for the header, then another for the UDP datagram.

Answer (score 2):

In UDP, one `send()` is a complete "message", you can't split a "message" across multiple `send()`s.

But TCP is a byte stream, so you can make multiple consecutive calls to `send()` per "message".  So, just send the data length in one `send()`, and then send the data in another `send()`.  TCP will ensure the bytes are received in the same order they are set sent. You don't have to prepend the length bytes to the `std::string` itself at all.

This works especially well if "Send Coalescing" (aka the Nagle Algorithm) is enabled, which is usually is by default.  That allows the socket stack to buffer outgoing data so it can send packets over the network more efficiently.  But even with Nagle disabled, this scheme will still work.

In fact, in TCP there is no guarantee that `send()` will accept all of the requested bytes in one go, so you have to be prepared to call `send()` multiple times anyway.

Try something like this:

```cpp
bool sendRaw(int sock, const void *data, size_t len)
{
    const char *pdata = static_cast<const char*>(data);
    while (len > 0)
    {
        int numSent = send(sock, pdata, len, 0);
        if (numSent < 0) return false; // or throw...
        pdata += numSent;
        len -= numSent;
    }
    return true;
}

bool sendUint16(int sock, uint16_t value)
{
    value = htons(value);
    return sendRaw(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
}

bool sendString(int sock, const std::string &s)
{
    if (s.size() > 0xFFFF) return false; // or throw...
    uint16_t len = static_cast<uint16_t>(s.size());
    bool ok = sendUint16(sock, len);
    if (ok) ok = sendRaw(sock, s.c_str(), len);
    return ok;
}
```

```
std::string udpData = ...;
bool ok = sendString(sock, udpData);
...
```

And then you can just reverse the process on the receiving side, eg:

```cpp
int recvRaw(int sock, void *data, size_t len)
{
    char *pdata = static_cast<char*>(data);
    while (len > 0)
    {
        int numRecvd = recv(sock, pdata, len, 0);
        if (numRecvd <= 0) return numRecvd; // or throw...
        pdata += numRecvd;
        len -= numRecvd;
    }
    return 1;
}

int recvUint16(int sock, uint16_t &value)
{
    int ret = recvRaw(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
    value = (ret == 1) ? ntohs(value) : 0;
    return ret;
}

int recvString(int sock, std::string &s)
{
    s.clear();
    uint16_t len;
    int ret = recvUint16(sock, len);
    if ((ret == 1) && (len > 0)) {
        s.resize(len);
        ret = recvRaw(sock, s.data()/*&s[0]*/, len);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

```
std::string udpData;
int ret = recvString(sock, udpData);
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but would it not impact performance of the application like for  1000 udp packets im running 2000 send() calls though with the prepend length scheme the send() call would be same as the number of packets.

Comment: @tingtong no, it will not really impact performance much if at all. Trying to actually prepend the length bytes to the `std::string` would impact performance more due to allocating new memory. This code is using the memory that is already allocated. And the socket has an internal buffer anyway, so it doesn't matter how many `send()` calls you make, the bytes have to be copied into that buffer first before the kernel will then transmit it.

Comment: I am little weak on how data is read/write in memory.
Is this valid logic:::
    `std::string sourceUdp = "Vivekananda";`
    `uint16_t sLen = static_cast<uint16_t>(sourceUdp.size());`
`std::string destTcp="";`
  `destTcp.append(std::to_string((0xFFFF)));`
  `destTcp.append(sourceUdp); ` 
  `destTcp.insert(0,std::to_string(sLen));`

Comment: @tingtong no, because your use of `to_string()` and `insert()` are not appropriate in this case, thus `destTcp` will not have anywhere near the correct format you want. Try this instead: `std::string destTcp(2+sLen, '\0'); *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&destTcp[0]) = htons(sLen); memcpy(&destTcp[2], sourceUdp.c_str(), sLen);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the end of the world to just do this right before sending. Allocating a temp buffer off the stack for a UDP packet (which won't be bigger than 64K anyway) - assuming synchronous socket sends will be fast.

```
unsigned char buffer[LONGEST_STRING_LENGTH+2];
size_t len = str.size();
// assert(len <= LONGEST_STRING_LENGTH);
uint16_t lenNBO = (uint16_t)len;
lenNBO = htons(lenNBO);
memcpy(buffer, &lenNBO, 2);
memcpy(buffer+2, str.c_str(), len);
send(sock, buffer, len+2, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of (C++) wrapper around sockets?
Otherwise, just pre-fill the string you receive data to with two arbitrary bytes, then append the data you receive from the socket. After that, write the length of the string into the first two offsets (minus two).

Something along the lines of

```
string x("xx");
// receive your data into x, starting at offset 2
x[0] = (x.length() - 2) & 0xff;
x[1] = ((x.length() - 2) & 0xff00) >> 8;
// send ...
```

Depending on which endianness you want, switch the 0 and 1 assignment. The code above writes it as little endian. Network byte order is considered to be big endian.

But tbh., if you're using the socket API directly, I'd use a plain char array instead of `std::string`.